# Links and controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am just getting started with this framework, and I'm fairly new to the MVC concept. Right now I am following the tutorial on the official documentation and my controller looks like this:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home')
{
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

public function goto($page)
{
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

}
```

I have also a home.php file with the homepage:

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url');?>
<div>
    <p>This is the home page</p>
</div>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()./index.php/pages/goto/about;?>">About</a>
<div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label> 
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Until now everything works, but how can I add and work with new links? I mean, suppose that you have a list of links in the homepage; when the user clicks on one of those links, how am I supposed to handle the requests? Should I let them go through the "pages" controller? Should I create a new controller for every page of the website?

In the first case (which to me sounds more logical), how can I correctly redirect the user based on the link they clicked on?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: usually you can write 1 controller/view/model and handle as many pages as you want, you need to store(database) somewhere the pages-title,pages-body and/or additional content so it can be *dynamically* generated/cached and manipulated easily..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix thank you very much for your comment. Can you make an example of what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how am I supposed to handle the requests?

Standard way is `controller/methods/` but ofcourse you can use router. [Router info](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

> Should I let them go through the "pages" controller?

Depends. Is those `pages` are related to controller? if yes, then include. if no than don't. Point is, bring together the related contents under one controller. You won't want say admin functions in `page` controller. do you?

> Should I create a new controller for every page of the website?

Simple answer. No. Reason is above.

> In the first case (which to me sounds more logical), how can I correctly redirect the user based on the link they clicked on?

again the 1st point.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply. "pages" is the controller, but the problem is that at the moment it only redirects me to the home page. Say I have something like "<a href="about.html>About page</a>", this would redirect me to the about page without going through the controller. Is this correct in the MVC concept?

Comment: `<a href="about.html>About page</a>` will give you the 404 error page unless you are using a rule in the router. If you indeed you use a router to say `about` in the form of `pages/about`, though in the url you will see only `about` [the method], it still will go into the `pages` controller.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not following. Indeed it gives me a 404 error, how should I change the link to make it work? I have tried '<a href="pages/view/about">About</a>' but it tells me that the page does not exist...

Comment: suppose your controller is `page` and method is `about`. The link should be, `<a href="<?php echo base_url()./index.php/page/about;?>">About</a>`. **Important** Don't forget to load the url helper.

Comment: I have updated my example code to show you exactly what I have at the moment, because it seems that I can't make it work :(

Comment: i am actually not understanding where you are getting stuck at.

Comment: The error I am currently receiving is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in myurl/.../home.php on line 5"..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19674/discussion-between-itachi-and-user1301428)